# export the returned results to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to call the returned results of the below api to some other function in another js file? I know this question is repeated, but not with returned results. So think before marking as a duplicate.

```
router.post("/:projectId/events/enriched", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
    const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        projectId: req.params.projectId, //taking from url
        description: req.body.description,
        regex: req.body.regex ,
        kafkaOptions: req.body.kafkaOptions     
    });
    return enrichedEvent.save()  // need all the saved data in another file 
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Event stored",
                createdEvent: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    projectId: result.projectId,
                    name: result.name,
                    description: result.description,
                    kafka: result.kafkaOptions,
                    filters: result.filters,
                    regex: result.regex,
                }
            });

            return Project.findOneAndUpdate({
                _id: result.projectId
            }, {
                $push: {
                    enrichedEvents: result._id
                }
            })
        })
       .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you'd like to get the result of `return enrichedEvent.save()…` from another JS file, without having to call the HTTP API?

If so, I'd suggest you to extract the logic from the API. You could do something like this:

```
// do-something.js
module.exports = function doSomething(projectId, options, onSave) {
  const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: options.name,
    projectId: projectId,
    description: options.description,
    regex: options.regex,
    kafkaOptions: options.kafkaOptions
  });

  return enrichedEvent
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      onSave(result);

      return Project.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: result.projectId
        },
        {
          $push: {
            enrichedEvents: result._id
          }
        }
      );
    });
}
```

Which you can call from your API:

```
const doSomething = require('./do-something');

router.post("/:projectId/events/enriched", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  return doSomething(req.params.projectId, req.body, (result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Event stored",
        createdEvent: {
          _id: result._id,
          projectId: result.projectId,
          name: result.name,
          description: result.description,
          kafka: result.kafkaOptions,
          filters: result.filters,
          regex: result.regex
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

And you could call `doSomething` from any other JS file, providing a different context:

`const doSomething = require('path/to/do-something');`

Note that I did some quick design decisions about the function signature and content, but it's up to you to determine where you want to separate things, and name them. The main idea is to extract the function by getting rid of everything which is API-specific.

Comment: options??? in the second parameter of dosomething(),  how does it matches req.body()?

Comment: could you please also write how to use this dosomething() function in other files. so that i can accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer to illustrate how to export the function and import it from other files. In this example, I put the function into another file, but it could be put in any file, along other functions. 

A good reference for exports/imports in node: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports